# Dongle Idle after some time (SMS Automating)

Tags: windows, sms

I wrote Java Application to send particular SMS and send it Using Dongle. I scheduled to run it at 4.30pm each day. and it plugged in to the windows machine.

My problem is that. when it not using for some time dongle getting Idle and my program couldn't find the device. when i plugged out the dongle and plug it again around 4.25pm. program can detect the dongle.

I solely think this is not a problem with a program and it happening because dongle is became idle after sometime.

Is there anyway to prevent it from getting Idle.

Thank you.